# Replaced method with long parameter list with builder pattern. How to test it with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, oop, testing, mockito

I had a long method that looked like this:

```
public class Executor {
   public void do(int a, int b, C c, D d, int e, int f);
}
```

I replaced this method with a builder pattern and call the method now like this:

```
executor.do(a).withB(b).withC(c).withD(d).withE(e).withF(f);
```

Previously, I tested my method like this using Mockito:

```
verify(mockExecutor).do(anyInt(), anyInt(), eq(c), eq(d), anyInt(), anyInt());
```

However, I can do that now. And I also can't use a ArgumentCaptor to capture an argument that is passed to a method. What can I do now?

Comment: You'll have to verify each `do` and `with` call separately.  Does each of them return the builder itself?  If so, you'll have to stub each one as well as verify it.  Perhaps if you can show us the code of the builder, I'll be able to give you a fuller answer with some actual code.

Comment: Now each of the methods returns an object of Class Request.

Comment: Then you'll need to mock `Request` as well as `Executor`, so you can verify the `with` calls.  It may be easier for you to use a spy instead of a mock for the `Request`, so that you don't have to stub each individual `with` call.

Answer (score 0):

With the example you provided it'd be difficult (but possible) to verify that mockExecutor has all method called because you'll have to mock now all methods and make sure they all return your mock object.

```
Executor executor = mock(Executor.class);
when(executor.do(anyInt())).thenReturn(executor);
when(executor.withB(anyInt())).thenReturn(executor);
...
when(executor.withF(anyInt())).thenReturn(executor);
```

so then you can verify all these methods are called.

```
verify(executor).do(anyInt())
...
verify(executor).withF(anyInt())
```

But this doesn't looks like a nice solution.
I'd recommend refactoring your code a bit to separate the Executor logic from data (let's call it ExecutorContext), like

```
ExecutorContext context = ExecutorContext.builder().withA(a).withB(b).withC(c).withD(d).withE(e).withF(f);

executor.do(context)
```

so that in test you can verify your executor easily with

```
verify(mockExecutor).do(any(ExecutorContext.class))
```

or with specific ExecutorContext (but don't forget to implement equals there)

Comment: I did this, but then in the second verify call i get a NullInsteadOfMockException

Comment: @FischerLudrian That happens when you pass null into verify method. Try to debug and see why the mock object is null.